# Using Phaxio with Rails 3.1 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to use the Phaxio API to include the ability to send faxes to customers from my Rails app, however I am having difficulty trying to implement it.  I know Phaxio is new and there doesn't seem to be much on it except for what is provided by their online docs, which don't really cover too much and have no examples using rails.

From what I can gather from their docs is that I need to send a request to https://api.phaxio.com/v1/send along with some parameters.  In their example they use curl to do this but how would I do this from a rails controller?  Is their any helper libraries out there for this or will I have to write it from scratch?  I might be swinging in the dark here but any help on this subject matter would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just sent over an email to you, but I'll post some example code here as well.  We're currently working on a Ruby helper for Phaxio, but here's some code that should help you get started in the mean time.

You'll need to gem install mime-types first.

http://pastebin.com/jfTLn6Bq

-Josh Nankin 
Co-Founder, Phaxio